# I can't achieve link of a CSS file from GitHub Page to Google blog

Tags: blogger, github-pages

I am trying to link a **CSS** file from a **GitHub Page** to a **Google blog** but it can't succeed!!! I am linking the CSS file like this...

```
<link href='https://fifamadness.github.io/host/css/global.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
```

If I open it using my browser I can see the CSS code normally. But as link into blog XML code, do nothing!!! Any idea why is this happening?

**EDIT**

I am sorry for this but it was my fault!!! On my rush, I put the link in wrong place into my XML code... Now it is working "like a charm"!!!

Answer (score 1):

seems, some of the github link doesn't give response as text/css so if the case it won't work that way, so try the same css with some cdn or just download css and upload yourself to cdn so you will get text/css response which will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not using [raw version](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FIFAMADNESS/host/master/css/global.css) of file.